# MVC 3 Scaffolding Template creation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm trying to generate a Controller usind the Scaffolding Template "Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework".

I created an ADO.net Data Entity Model and connected it to an MSSQL 2008 DB (hosted by GoDaddy) and I am able to select the correct Model class and Data context class, but when I click "Add", I get the following error:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Project.Models.ModelClass'. The entry 'ProjectDataContext' has already been added. (C:\Users...\Temp\tmpD167.tmp line 13)

The file "tmpD167.tmp" is a copy of my web.config

Line 13 is a connection string that looks like this (post sanitation):

```
    <add name="ProjectDataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Project.csdl|res://*/Models.Project.ssdl|res://*/Models.Project.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=project.db.12345678.hostedresource.com;initial catalog=projectdb;persist security info=True;user id=projectdbuser;password=Password00##;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have 2 other connection strings (one for ApplicationServices and the other for the project data) that are on lines 11 and 12.

Is my connection string formatted correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you remove your .edmx file and the reference to it in the web config and thenrecreate it?

Comment: I tried that.  Originally the .edmx was in another project, but that too didn't work.  I'll try it again thou

Comment: Blah, it's always the last place that you look!  I was removing the connections from the web.config and I realized that I reused the name for 2 of the connections!  Changed the name and everything worked!  +1 for making me go back :)